# Query (SOQL) on connectedApplication to get clientId and clientSecreet

Tags: connected-apps, client-id

I am creating a connected app through metadataservice. But i am not able to retrieve the clientId and clientSecret from this newly created connected app in apex class

Comment: why would you expect there be API access to a clientSecret?

Comment: I need to send these details back to the external system once the connected app is created upon their request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You can use "readMetadata" method from "Metadataservice" class to retrieve the consumerKey.

https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls

Answer (score -1):

it is not possible to retrieve the **client_id** and **client_secret** for a connected app directly within Apex in Salesforce. The **client_id** and **client_secret** are sensitive information and should be kept secure. In Salesforce, these values are typically generated when you create a connected app through the Salesforce Setup menu.

If you still wanna to retrieve **client_id** and **client_secret**, you can use custom metadata. Create a custom metadata and store the **client_id** and **client_secret** on it. And use it in apex like:

**CustomMetadataRecord__mdt customMetadata= CustomMetadataRecord__mdt.getInstance('customMetadataRecordName');
String clientId = (String)myMetadata.Client_Id__c;
String clientSecret = (String)myMetadata.Client_Secret__c;**

Comment: I have created a REST resource that will be accessed by an external system to create a connected app. Once the connected app is created, I want to send this information back. Can you suggest a way to achieve this besides using custom metadata?

Comment: No others way to get client_id and client_secret dynamically.